# I left my Camera unused for 4 years

Tags: battery, canon-60d

I have Cannon 60D camera, I stopped using it for 5 years long, do you think It could be working?
I’ve been charging the battery for hours but it’s not full yet, and every time I put it in, the camera doesn’t turn on

Yes, the battery was in the whole time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you left the battery in the camera whilst storing it, the battery has been fully discharged which will damage Lithium Ion batteries. I'm not sure about Canon cameras, but Nikon cameras have about a 200 uA current consumption when the camera is either in sleep mode and when the power switch is in the off position. If you have access to a voltmeter, check the battery voltage.

There is also another rechargeable battery (not accessible by the average user) in the camera body. When fully drained, it can take 4 to 6 hours for that battery to charge from the battery that you normally charge.

Chances are, the main battery you charge is damaged. If you decide to get a new battery, charge it, then install it in the camera and let the camera sit for at least 4 hours so the internal battery can be charged.

In the future, recharge the battery at least two times per year if you are going to store the camera for a long period of time.

Comment: In Canon 60D there is not internal battery for realtime clock. AFAIK it use kind of supercapacitor.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have seen a take-apart video for the 60D where they replace the internal battery and also discussions that the 60D uses a super capacitor.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar experience with a 450D that I left with a family who didn't use it for a couple of years before returning it. The batteries (the one in the camera plus a spare) were dead, I just replaced them with new decent off-brand batteries, and I can use that camera again for side projects.